# What adaptions would a human need to open their jaws as wide as a snake's?

Tags: humans, anatomy, adaptability, snake

Would it be a simple change of bone shape? Muscles? Keep in mind, this adaption is **not** for swallowing bigger food, as the human throat path makes that difficult, but is instead is for intimidating predators.

Comment: What research have you done thus far?

Comment: Human jaws are attached directly to the braincase, which inhibits movement, while snakes have a whole extra hinge. I just don't know if I can copy and paste the shape of a snake's jaw onto a human and have it work.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to have a stronger bite against a predator (and the jaw joint as it is helps this a lot); donning on a mask to make my face scarier is easy enough. But what do I know, I'm only a human :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest adaptation would be to have the jaw mimicking the one of [snakes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrq7y.png), where the quadrate bone act as a hinge between the skull and the lower jaw.

[image]

Additionally, having the lower jaw not fused but held by a ligament would allow for further spreading.

Comment: You should add something about fixing the fused jugal bar ("zygomatic arch") of humans, and otherwise adapting the upper jaw to be able to move again.

Comment: IVE RETURNED WITH A REBUTTAL. 21 days late I know, but humans do not in fact have a quadrate bone! Now I have no idea what to do with that info.